# JSON and PHP - pulling data from the stock exchange

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am struggling to find a solution to a PHP/JSON issue.  I have written a script that shows stock market pricing using a URL that pulls down a JSON file. I am new to PHP and I can't seem to access the individual elements in the JSON file.

Here is my script:

http://data.asx.com.au/data/1/share/TLS/prices?interval=daily&count=1

```
$price = file_get_contents('http://data.asx.com.au/data/1/share/TLS/prices?interval=daily&count=1');
$fileprices = json_decode($price, true);
print_r ($fileprices);
```

This returns :

```
[data] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [code] => FET
        [close_date] => 2017-11-06T00:00:00+1100
        [close_price] => 2.81
        [change_price] => 0.01
        [volume] => 85278
        [day_high_price] => 2.83
        [day_low_price] => 2.78
        [change_in_percent] => 0.357%
        )
    )
```

How can I access the element [code] and return the data FET or any other element?

I have tried numerous methods without success.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried `$fileprices['data'][0]['code']` ..?

Comment: do this **echo $fileprices['data'][0]['code']**

Comment: @Zaheer Attar how about data ?

Comment: ???. You don't understand Array access?

Answer (score 1):

In case you have multiple elements returned via api call you can loop over the `$fileprices['data']` using `forEach()` and get the required elements.

```
forEach($fileprices['data'] as $key=>$value) {
   print_r($filePrices['data'][$key]['code']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$price = file_get_contents('http://data.asx.com.au/data/1/share/TLS/prices?interval=daily&count=1');
$fileprices = json_decode($price, true);
$data = $fileprices['data'][0];
```

and then you can try to echo $data['code']; or echo $data['close_price']; or else

Comment: Thank you.  I used a variation of the above... seems to work very well.

Comment: @mitchy please upvote or green check if this answer is useful :D

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not passing the `, true` flag to `json_decode()`, which converts the whole response into an associative array for seemingly no reason. A JSON object is, by default, an object, and there's no need to convert to an array in this case. Nothing wrong with it, but no reason either.

With that said, here's an example showing how to use the default behavior of `json_decode()` to get the properties you're looking for.

```
<?php
$response = file_get_contents('http://data.asx.com.au/data/1/share/TLS/prices?interval=daily&count=1');
$response = $response ? json_decode($response) : null;

if ( $response instanceof StdClass ) {
    echo $response->data[0]->code."\n";
    echo $response->data[0]->close_price."\n";
    echo $response->data[0]->change_price."\n";
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  This works and provides a good understanding.